# pandas grup by get top 5 percent score

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am working with a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
score  name  country   date   id
1     name1  country1  date1  id1
5     name1  country1  date2  id2
6     name1  country1  date3  id3
9     name2  country2  date1  id4
5     name2  country2  date2  id5
5     name2  country2  date2  id5
7     name2  country3  date2  id5
2     name2  country3  date2  id5
1     name2  country3  date3  id6
2     name3  country4  date1  id7
6     name3  country4  date1  id8
7     name3  country4  date1  id9
```

I would like to get the the ids for each name grouped by country, where the score is the top 5% from that group of name. In the end it should look something like this:

```
name   country   score date  id
name1  country1    6   date2 id2
                   5   date3 id3
name2  country2    9   date2 id2
name2  country3    7   date2 id2
name3  country4    7   date2 id2
```

Comment: Why are there in the desired output 2 rows for country1?
How is the date and id column aggregated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC,

```
g = df.groupby('country')
g.apply(lambda r: r[r.score >= r.score.quantile(0.95)])


                score   name    country     date    id
country                     
country1    2   6      name1    country1    date3   id3
country2    3   9      name2    country2    date1   id4
country3    6   7      name2    country3    date2   id5
country4    11  7      name3    country4    date1   id9
```

Comment: you are amazing!!! btw, any idea why in this case g returns a df and not a groupby object?

Comment: `g` returns a a groupby object, but `g.apply` returns a df :) Glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupby` + `transform` with `quantile`. For example, for the top 60%:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'UK', 5], ['A', 'UK', 2], ['A', 'UK', 3], ['A', 'UK', 6],
                   ['B', 'US', 2], ['B', 'US', 5], ['B', 'US', 1], ['B', 'US', 11]],
                  columns=['name', 'country', 'score'])

quantile = df.groupby(['name', 'country'])['score'].transform('quantile', 0.60)
mask = df['score'] > quantile

res = df[mask]

print(res)

  name country  score
0    A      UK      5
3    A      UK      6
5    B      US      5
7    B      US     11
```